# What kind of me?

Tags: riddle

When I small, I am nine.

When I big, I am six.

Everyone likes me when I have nice time playing.

Sometimes everyone call me the seventh

What am I?

Comment: sorry for my bad in english language, i can provide more vulgar clue, but its not kind for little children

Comment: The [meta-knowledge] tag doesn't look correct to me. Should it perhaps be [knowledge]?

Comment: If you replace "have nice time" with "have a nice time", it will read much better as English, but of course that might break some bit of wordplay or something so I'm not going to make the change without the creator's approval...

Comment: Similarly for "When I" -> "When I am" in the first two lines.

Comment: the next clue is: i have use it in the question, but not use it in this comment

Comment: by the way thanks to @GarethMcCaughan and moderator to fix my grammar in question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I' am

> the letter **G**

When I small, I am nine.

> a small **g** often looks like a 9

When I big, I am six.

> a big **G** often looks like a 6

Everyone likes me when I have nice time playing.

> Players often say **gg** (good game) after playing

Sometimes everyone call me the seventh

> Its the seventh letter of the alphabet.

Hint in comment: i have use it in the question, but not use it in this comment

> yeah, the comment is written without the letter G

Comment: That's what i mean, Good Answer

Comment: The vulgar clue is probably about the rot13(T fcbg)